# OSX 10.8.4 RVM install troubles with Network Users

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby 1.9 as the system default for all users of our mac machines.

I've installed RVM using a "local" user account and everything seems to be working fine.

I'm able to run the rvm function test and install Ruby 1.9.3 as the system default.

```
type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a function

$:~ admin$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
```

When I log in from a Domain User account I get the following prompt at the command line.

```
 Last login: Tue Jul 30 14:29:02 on console
 -sh: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
 $:~ nick$
```

There seems to be a permissions issues lurking somewhere but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see:

```
 -sh: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
```

suggests that you use `sh` shell - this is **not** supported shell, you need to switch the user to `bash`:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash $USER
```

I'm not sure if it needs any extra params for domain users or if you need to use different command for it - but you need to change the shell to `bash`.